# Store value from for loop into array?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Given this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (col_A[i] == row_B[j])
        {
            printf("%d %d %2.2f\n",
                   row_A[i], col_B[j], val_A[i] * val_B[j]);
            val_D[i] = val_A[i] * val_B[j];
            row_D[i] = row_A[i];
            col_D[j] = col_B[j];
        }
    }
}
```

With the following output:

```
1 1 3.00
1 2 3.00
1 1 3.00
2 1 3.00
2 2 4.00
3 1 4.00
3 2 4.00
3 1 6.00

row_D = [ 1 1 2 2 3 3 0 0 ]
col_D = [ 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 ]
val_D = [ 3.00 3.00 3.00 4.00 4.00 6.00 0.00 0.00 ]
```

What is the proper method for storing the values into val_D, row_D and col_D correctly? Row_D should contain the values from the 1st column of the 3-tuple, Col_D the 2nd column and Val_D the 3rd column.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it what you already did?

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a counter variable and increment it only if there is an update.

```
counter = 0
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (col_A[i] == row_B[j])
        {
            printf("%d %d %2.2f\n",
                   row_A[i], col_B[j], val_A[i] * val_B[j]);
            val_D[counter] = val_A[i] * val_B[j];
            row_D[counter] = row_A[i];
            col_D[counter] = col_B[j];
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
}
```